# Create new record button using Visual Basic and SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

Sorry I am very new to the world of programming! I was wondering how I would create a new record button in visual basic with SQL.

Am I right in using a INSERT statement.

I have been trying for hours with no luck.

Any help is most appreciated. :)

Comment: How have you tried using INSERT so far and why hasn't it worked? It will be a lot easier for people to help you if you provide example code.

Answer (score 0):

ok I'm going to make some assumptions. I am going to assume you are using aspx web forms and server controls. visual basic could be alot of things web forms, mvc, windows forms, web api...  anyway here is an example using aspx web forms.

so for your aspx page something like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="insert.aspx.cs" Inherits="webApiOracle.insert" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Insert</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="TextBoxemail">Email</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxemail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword">First Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="TextBoxLastName">Last Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLastName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Insert" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

then in your code behind.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Namespace webApiOracle
    Public Partial Class insert
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        End Sub

        Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Using conn As New SqlConnection("connectionString")
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
                    cmd.Connection = conn
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mytable(email,first_name,last_name) " & vbCr & vbLf & "                            VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)"

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", TextBoxemail.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", TextBoxFirstName.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", TextBoxLastName.Text)

                    Try
                        conn.Open()
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Catch [error] As SqlException

                        Label1.Text = [error].Message.ToString()

                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: sorry my aspx says c# but my code behind is vb I used telerik code converter to switch the code behind from c# to vb.